# In CKEditor, how do I change the "indent" plugin to 20px instead of 40px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ckeditor

When I push "indent" on CKEDITOR, it creates a div with margin-left 40.

How can I change that number to 20?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.indentOffset

Below is the applicable source excerpt:

`var indentOffset = editor.config.indentOffset || 40;`

Comment: That doc led me to my answer: indentClasses. Why use inline styles when you can class that kid?

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly set in your editors config file

In config.js

```js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
  config.indentOffset = 20;
};
```